# Extracting values scoped inside a Nokogiri each block

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to create a function that will scrape the filmography of actors from wikipedia pages. This is an example of the code

```
doca = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon"))

grandparent = doca.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]').children() 
child = []

grandparent.each {|node|
  node.children.each{|x|
    if x['id'] == "Films"
      child = node.next_element.children
      break
    end
  }
}
```

Each element of the child array now contains one row of the filmography table. What i really want is to save the href link for each film into an array but am having trouble accessing them as they are well nested within each. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Rather than screenscraping wikipedia to get at structured data, you might consider using e.g. http://wiki.dbpedia.org/About, who have already extracted that kind of data and can be accessed using SPARQL (e.g. the query "select distinct ?films where {?films <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/starring> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kevin_Bacon> } LIMIT 100" on their SPARQL endpoint at http://dbpedia.org/sparql)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jamey
I'm afraid it's a college assignment where I have to use nokogiri to scrape an actors wiki page for a list of films they've been in. Thanks for the resource link though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
doca.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table//td[2]//i/a').map { |a| a['href'] }
```

That selects links in italics at any depth within a column (`td`) in a table directly inside a `div` with id `mw-content-text`, then maps them to their `href` attribute (i.e. their link value). You could be more specific, depending on what you want to include/exclude.

If you want the links to be absolute and not relative, you can merge the page URL to the link value:

```
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon"
doca.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]/table//td[2]//a').map { |a| URI(url).merge(a['href']) }
```

UPDATE:

Alternatively, if you want to do search for the links the way you described, you could do this:

```
doca.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]//table[preceding-sibling::*[1][span[@id="Films"]]]//a').map { |a| a['href'] }
```

This says: find all links that are children of a table inside a div with id `mw-content-text` whose direct preceding sibling has a direct child span tag with `id` "Films". Somewhat more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was stuck for hours. The last answer is perfect!

Comment: You're welcome! As @pguardiario suggested Xpath can be pretty complicated so many people avoid it, but in the end you should use whatever comes most naturally to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to get at the film list:

```
doca.at('span#Films').parent.search('+ table tr')[1..-1].each do |tr|
  puts tr.at('a')[:href] rescue 'N/A'
end
```

You should avoid xpath whenever possible (imho)

Answer (score 0):

To get/save all the href links, just add the following lines to your given code :

```
hrefs = child.css('td a').map{|i| i.attributes['href'].value}
//puts hrefs
```

That's it. So, the whole code snippet for getting all the href links of that table:

```
doca = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon"))

grandparent = doca.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]').children() 
child = []

grandparent.each {|node|
  node.children.each{|x|
    if x['id'] == "Films"
      child = node.next_element.children
      break
    end
  }
}

hrefs = child.css('td a').map{|i| i.attributes['href'].value}
    //puts hrefs
```